# How to format a distance matrix as an array in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a distance matrix d that I would like to format as an array in Rmarkdown.

````
```{r,echo=FALSE}
x <- c(1,3,1,4,5)
y <- c(5,4,3,5,1)
d <- dist(cbind(x,y))
```
````

So that d looks something like this in a Rmarkdown document:

```
$$\mathbf{d} = \left[\begin{array}
{rrrrr}
~ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
2 & 2.236 & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
3 & 2.000 & 2.236 & ~ & ~ \\
4 & 3.000 & 1.414 & 3.606 & ~ \\
5 & 5.657 & 3.606 & 4.472 & 4.123
\end{array}\right]
$$
```

Any tips to do this without hardcoding?

EDIT: fixed typo in array TeX code.

Comment: You should be able to put `\`\`\`{r, echo = TRUE}` right inside your TeX array after `{rrr}` then loop through `d` and `cat` the values with appropriate values for `sep` and/or `collapse`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate a markdown table instead of LaTeX (and then transform that to LaTeX/PDF/docx/whatever), then it would be pretty straightforward to add support for the `dist` class in the `pander` package. Quick example on this idea:

```
> m <- as.matrix(d)
> m[upper.tri(m)] <- NA
> pander(m, split.table = Inf, digits = 4, missing = '', keep.trailing.zeros = TRUE)

-----------------------------
  1     2     3     4     5  
----- ----- ----- ----- -----
0.000                        

2.236 0.000                  

2.000 2.236 0.000            

3.000 1.414 3.606 0.000      

5.657 3.606 4.472 4.123 0.000
-----------------------------
```

Please create a ticket/pull request at https://github.com/Rapporter/pander if you want to get this done as a simple `pander(d)` call.